# Condition number for matrices

Tags: numerical-methods

I am looking at condition number for matrices in numerics.

On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices), there is an estimate about the sequence space of all bounded sequences. 
Can someone point me to a good idea how this follows from the definition of $\kappa(A) = \|A\| \|A^{-1}\|$ above?

Comment: Edited. Was an old question I didn't ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\ell_\infty$ you obviously have $\|A\|\ge \max_i |a_{ii}|$ for lower-triangular operators $A$.

Also, the inverse operator $A^{-1}$ is lower triangular and has the elements $\frac{1}{a_{ii}}$ on its diagonal. Therefore, its norm satisfies $$\|A^{-1}\|\ge \max_i \frac{1}{|a_{ii}|} = \frac{1}{\min_i |a_{ii}|} .$$

These two estimations allow you to conclude that $$\kappa(A)\ge \frac{\max_i |a_{ii}|}{\min_i |a_{ii|}}$$ for lower triangular operators $A$.